# \ifmmode self-contradictory in amsmath (OK in just LaTeX)

Tags: macros, amsmath, expansion

File:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\newcommand{\argghhh}{\relax\ifmmode\bar\else\expandafter\=\fi}

\begin{document} 

$ \argghhh a $ 

\end{document}
```

produces error (but NOT if `\usepackage{amsmath}` is commented out):

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \= invalid in math mode on input line 7.

! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.
\add@accent ...@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 
                                                  #1 #2\egroup \spacefactor ...
l.7 $ \argghhh a
                 $
```

Clearly this is math mode.  But it chooses
(1) `\=`, hence NOT math mode, then
(2) complains about `\=` in math mode!

Answer (score 13):

adding `\tracingall` you will see that `\bar` is selected but its argument is `\else`

```
\bar ->\protect \mathaccentV {bar}016
{\relax}

\mathaccentV #1#2#3#4#5->\ifmmode \gdef \macc@tmp {\macc@depth \@ne }\setbox \z
@ \hbox {\let \mathaccentV \macc@test \let \use@mathgroup \@gobbletwo \let \sel
ect@group \@gobblethree \frozen@everymath {}$#5$}\macc@tmp \ifnum \macc@depth =
\@ne \global \let \macc@nucleus \@empty \mathaccent "\accentclass@ \else \@xp \
macc@nested \fi #2#3#4{#5}\macc@nucleus \else \@xp \nonmatherr@ \csname #1\endc
sname \fi 
#1<-bar
#2<-0
#3<-1
#4<-6
#5<-\else
```

You need the `\else` to expand before `\bar` is called.

```
\newcommand{\argghhh}{\relax\ifmmode\expandafter\bar\else\expandafter\=\fi}
```

The reasons why you don't get an error without `amsmath` are mainly accidental related to the fact that in that case you get the TeX primitive argument scanning which differs from the way macro arguments are scanned.